# Is Beam Search a deep learning tool?

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I've been working on the Beam Search algorithm for a scheduling problem
I have a question about it, is a a Deep Learning tool (as it uses RNN) or an AI heuristic ?

Thank you

I still cannot understand fully the difference between AI and Deep learning

Comment: If it uses an RNN, it does use deep learning. I don’t know what an AI heuristic is. I have not seen that term before.

Comment: Beam search does not "use RNN", it's far more general than that. Just checking Wikipedia would tell you as much.

Comment: Then it's not a Deep Learning tool, right ?